Parent Theme Error: Trying to access array offset on value of type null
I would like to start off by thanking you for taking the time to read this.  I am not familiar with coding, as I have not coded since my freshman year of college over a decade ago, so this is probably something simple, that I am overlooking.
I am trying to update our website to PHP 8.2 (currently on 8.0), whenever I attempt to update the staging site on GoDaddy to PHP 8.2, I get the following error:
Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /var/www/wp-content/themes/construction/inc/extras.php on line 281
Which is referring to the parent theme on our website.
When I look at the area of code specified, it shows me:
    function wpcharming_change_portfolio_labels( array $args ) {
        global $wpc_option;
    
        $custom_slug = 'project';
        if ( $wpc_option['custom_project_slug'] != '' ) {
            $custom_slug = trim( $wpc_option['custom_project_slug'] );
        }
    
        $labels = array(
            'name'               => __( 'Projects', 'wpcharming' ),
            'singular_name'      => __( 'Project', 'wpcharming' ),
            'add_new'            => __( 'Add New Item', 'wpcharming' ),
            'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Project', 'wpcharming' ),
            'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Project', 'wpcharming' ),
            'new_item'           => __( 'Add New Project', 'wpcharming' ),
            'view_item'          => __( 'View Item', 'wpcharming' ),
            'search_items'       => __( 'Search Projects', 'wpcharming' ),
            'not_found'          => __( 'No projects found', 'wpcharming' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No projects found in trash', 'wpcharming' ),
        );
        $args['labels'] = $labels;
    
        // Update project single permalink format, and archive slug as well.
        $args['rewrite']     = array( 'slug' => $custom_slug );
        $args['has_archive'] = false;
        // Don't forget to visit Settings->Permalinks after changing these to flush the rewrite rules.
    
        return $args;
    }
    add_filter( 'portfolioposttype_args', 'wpcharming_change_portfolio_labels' );

With line 281 that the logs show as causing the error being:
    if ( $wpc_option['custom_project_slug'] != '' ) {
            $custom_slug = trim( $wpc_option['custom_project_slug'] );
        }

It seems that no matter what I try, it results in the same error regarding the value being null.
Unfortunately, this theme stopped being supported quite a few years ago, so I am not able to reach out to the developer for assistance.
Do you have any thoughts on how I could modify this code to function properly without giving an error? If you need to see the rest of the code of extras.php let me know and I can provide it.
PS Edit: The comment by CBroe worked.  Thank you very much.  I do not see anywhere I can click a green checkmark to indicate that is the answer.

Error means that $wpc_option must be NULL to begin with, so if you make that if ( $wpc_option && $wpc_option['custom_project_slug'] != '' ), it should probably be enough already to avoid the error message. Whether it will still work as intended, we can't tell for sure from the outside. If your site only used the default slug project for this custom post type(?) and didn't change it to anything custom via some settings page, it should probably work fine though.

That you CBroe, this worked!  I am not sure how to mark this as the solution/answer, as I do not see a checkmark anywhere.
